# How to get the radius of a flat piece of paper that is then rolled once into a cylinder please....

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

How do I get the radius of a flat piece of paper that is then rolled once into a cylinder using only the original dimensions from the flat piece of paper? In other words, just using the height and the width? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture (or physically do it). You will see that the end which forms the circular end of the cylinder used to be a side of the paper.

Let's say that end of the cylinder used to be the width of the paper. Then that width is equal to the circumference of the circle.

Use $C = 2\pi r$ to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rolling height-wise (height $H$) and width $W$, then $ r =\dfrac{W}{ 2\pi}$.